# Why does pandas DataFrame append does not work?

Tags: python, pandas

My code

```
import glob

import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

f_name = glob.glob('*.json')
result_df = pd.DataFrame()
filepath = 'proba.parquet'
for f in f_name:
    with open(f, encoding='utf-8', mode='r') as i:
        data = pd.read_json(i, lines=True)
    result_df.append(data)
    print(result_df)
    table_from_pandas = pa.Table.from_pandas(result_df)
    pq.write_table(table_from_pandas, filepath)
```

I am looking line by line for error.

What print show us

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

What am I doing wrong? What is wrong with my append?

Comment: Try `result_df = result_df.append(data)`

Comment: works perfect,thanks a lot.